# Where to ask question about disk usage by MySQL on CentOS?

Tags: support, scope, site-recommendation

I'm currently facing a problem where MySQL took 10 GB of my disk usage within a few hours due to some restoration errors with gz file.

I'm not sure if I should ask this here, as it's full of MySQL questions regarding similar issues, Database Administrator, Unix or Server Fault. Can anybody point me towards the best fitting place for it?

To summarize the problem, I made a database.gz file with mysqldump from a live server and now I'm trying to restore it in a new development environment using Vagrant, Virtual Box, CentOS and MySQL. I tried to restore the file a few times and all of them failed. That's when I noticed my SSD disk space was gone.

Comment: I could point you to the best fitting place for MySQL, but I would get suspended again:(

Comment: @MartinJames yeah, MySQL is kind of like Bieber famous. Nobody likes, everyone talks about it and it keeps famous. Kind of like the notion that "everything written in Delphi is a malware" or that one "If Java truly had a garbage collector, most programs written in it would delete itself in the first run".

Comment: My bet is Server Fault. It sounds like a technical question about MySQL itself, and not a question about SQL, etc.

Comment: You should ask this type of site-recommendation question on the uber meta, http://meta.stackexchange.com. That way, you are more likely to catch the eye of people who know about more sites than Stack Overflow. For example, DBA.SE exists, but I have no idea whether this would be on topic there because I've literally never been to the site.